# Why does the Causal Impact Analysis uses Bayesian Structural Time Series Model?

Tags: causality, bsts

So, I have been studying causality and came across with Googles Causality Impact Analysis.

I already read the paper and watched Kay's keynote. However, I wonder if it is also possible to use a simple regression or a machine learning model build the synthetic post intervention series.

Comment: Check out the [synthetic-cohort] tag for a frequentist approaches.